# Link to different TLD but the same URI

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, uri

Hi I need to create a button to link to a different TLD with the same URI

For example

```
http://website.com/page1
```

Will have a button that links to

```
http://website.co.uk/page1
```

I am thinking something like

```
<a href="<?php echo('http://website.co.uk'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>">LINK HERE</a>
```

however this clearly isn't working ?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

When I test this I end up with the following

[image]

linking to

```
https://website.com/page1/%3C?php%20echo(%27http://website.co.uk%27.$_SERVER[
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine in my test. Please describe what your actual issue is with it.

Comment: But how are `/page1` and `/page2` even _“the same URI”_ to begin with?

Comment: In your expected link you changed the domain name and the page, not the TLD.

Comment: sorry guys please check my updated text now. Thanks :D

Comment: "isn't working" doesn't tell us much.  What is the expected result?  What is the actual result?

Comment: please see my screen shot & added info above now, thank you Patrick

Comment: Looks to me like you don't actually have PHP running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: it's on a wordpress site so I definatly have PHP there. Is there a non PHP way of doing this?

Comment: sorry PHP isn't executable by default in wordpress posts & pages...

Comment: you wrote this php code into a WP HTML editor ? It has been saved as text.